# Import inlined js script webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm writing an Angular application using Webpack.

I have a user profile JavaScript object that I'd like to template into the index page via an inline script, for performance, so that the client doesn't have make another request and delay the rest of the page loading.

Using requirejs you can name an inlined module so you can depend on it later. Is there any way of doing this webpack? or am I stuck with declaring it as a global?

As an example here's what you could do in Require JS;

```
<html>
<body>
...
<script>
define('userProfile', [
  'angular'
], function(angular) {
  return angular.module('userProfile', [])
    .constant('userProfile', Object.freeze({
      id: '$!{user.userid}',
      name: '$!{user.fullname}',
      userType: '$!{user.userType}'
    }))
});
</script>
...
</body>
</html>
```

The user fields  such as `'$!{user.userid}'` are templated in when the index page is served.

To depend on this in your app you could simply do something like

```
define([
    'userProfile',
], function() {    
  return angular.module('my-app', [
        'userProfile',
  ]);
});
```

Comment: can you share an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a variable or module to be external on your webpack config so that you just include it on the page by a script tag. This is what i do to skip libraries bundle with my script

```
// webpack.config.js
 "externals": {
            "jquery": "jQuery",
            "angular": "angular"
        },
```

But as angular works you don't need to import the module with webpack

```
<script>
(function(angular) {
  angular.module('userProfile', [])
    .constant('userProfile', Object.freeze({
      id: '$!{user.userid}',
      name: '$!{user.fullname}',
      userType: '$!{user.userType}'
    }))
})(angular);
</script>
```

And in your module you can.

```
angular.module('whatever', ['userProfile'])
```

Now you can use the user profile constant anywhere in your angular application.

```
angular.module('whatever').controller(['userProfile', function (userProfile) {}]);
```

You just need to make sure that the userProfile script is executed before the your bundle